# How to create a randomized deck of cards?

Tags: java

I need to create a deck of cards by using two string: "HSCD" and "A2345678910JQK".

```
public class Deck {
Random random=new Random();
Queue cards=new Queue(112);
String suits="HSCD";
String rands="A2345678910JQK";

public Deck() {
    for (int i = 0; i < suits.length(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < rands.length(); j++) {
            char suit = suits.charAt(random.nextInt(suits.length()));
            char rand = rands.charAt(random.nextInt(rands.length()));
            if (rand == '1' || rand == '0') {
                String s = Integer.toString(10);
                cards.enqueue(new Card(suit, s));
            } else {
                String s1 = Character.toString(rand);
                cards.enqueue(new Card(suit, s1));
            }
        }
    }
}
public void display(){
    for (int i = 0; i < cards.size(); i++) {
        System.out.print(cards.peek());
        cards.enqueue(cards.dequeue());
    }
}

public Queue getCards() {
    return cards;
}

public void setCards(Queue cards) {
    this.cards = cards;
}

public String getSuits() {
    return suits;
}

public void setSuits(String suits) {
    this.suits = suits;
}

public String getRands() {
    return rands;
}

public void setRands(String rands) {
    this.rands = rands;
}}
```

I have Deck and Card classes.

```
public class Card {

private char rand;
private String suit;

public Card(char rand, String suit) {
    this.rand = rand;
    this.suit = suit;
}

public Card(){}

public char getRand() {
    return rand;
}

public void setRand(char rand) {
    this.rand = rand;
}

public String getSuit() {
    return suit;
}

public void setSuit(String suit) {
    this.suit = suit;
}

public String toString(){
    return "\t"+rand + suit;
}}
```

But i couldn't solve that every suits must have 13 rands. In my program my deck is randomly created. And my deck must be shuffled. I can't use list or array structures because teacher told us so :). Can you help me?

Comment: Create the cards and add them to an ArrayList. Then use the Collections.shuffle(…) method to shuffle all the cards.

Comment: @WJS, and yet you provided an answer using my suggestion? I thought this was the OP's homework question. I only tried to point them in the right direction.

Comment: @camickr Actually, someone else suggested an answer using an ArrayList before your comment.  And I had already considered that and shuffle as a solution (since both are pretty obvious) as well as some other suggestions.  But I decided to remove my answer since those suggestions would require a major overhaul of the OPs current code.

Comment: @WJS Do you have a solution for my case?

Comment: @kuzeypi Is there any reason you are using Queue class?  Is that a homegrown class? Using an `ArrayList` and `Collections.shuffle` as @camickr had suggested would make your task signficantly easier.

Comment: Yes its a homework. So i can only use queue.

Answer (score 1):

1. You are creating 14 cards per suit, not 13: you're creating `10` twice. Remove with `0` or `1` from `rands`.
2. It will be easier if you first create the cards, then shuffle them.

Creation of cards should be similar to what you're already doing, minus the randomization - just go through suits and values in order:

```
for each suit:
  for each value:
    sortedCards.add(new Card(suit, value));
```

Then, shuffle the cards as follows:

```
while (sortedCards is not empty):
  shuffledCards.add(sortedCards.get(random.nextInt(sortedCards.size())))
```

Comment: does  shuffledCards.add(sortedCards.get(random.nextInt(sortedCards.size()))) remove each card from sortedCards?

Comment: As written it doesn't, but yes, it should

Answer (score 0):

Just duplicate four time the second string. After you take two random numbers one correspond to the sign and one to the number. Finally you put sign+number in memory and you remove the number in the string :

```java
String signs = "HSCD";
String numbersH = "A2345678910JQK";
String numbersS = "A2345678910JQK";
String numbersC = "A2345678910JQK";
String numbersD = "A2345678910JQK";
ArrayList<String> deck = new ArrayList<String>();
Random random = new Random();
while(deck.size()<52){
   int sign = random.nextInt(signs.lenght());
   if(sign==0 && numbersH.lenght()>0){
      int number = random.nextInt(numbersH.lenght());
      deck.add(signs.charAt(sign)+numbersH.charAt(number));
      numbersH = numbersH.substring(0,number)+numberH.substring(number+1);
   }//here the same for other signs

}
```

Comment: Replace ArrayList by Queue

Comment: "//here remove form numbersH the char at number"   How do i do that?Thank you

Comment: I replaced the line ^^

Comment: It enters to an infinite loop.

Comment: you do the same for other lines ? dont forget to create deck.size() wich return the number of card in deck

Comment: verify subString() methods, i'm not sure about limits. I update the program too

Answer (score 0):

You haven't included the `Queue` class so help is going to be limited.  Here are some other suggestions.

```
        String suits="HSCD";
        String ranks="A23456789TJQK";
        for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
            int suit = i/13; // index into suit 0 to 3 inclusive
            int rank = i%13; // index into rank 0 to 12 inclusive
            cards.enqueue(new Card(suits.charAt(suit), ranks.charAt(rank));
        }
```

Also, quite often, card game software uses a `T` for ten, which is what I did in this example. It can be changed but in your implementation you can't store 10 as as a single character and it is cumbersome to maintain two types for card ranks.  So you should probably make all your ranks and suits as type `String`.

Answer (score 0):

Another method : Create your deck like iluxa say you and shuffle with this :

```java
Random rand = new Random();
for(int i=0;i<300;i++){
   int a = rand.nextInt(deck.size());
   int b = rand.nextInt(deck.size());
   Card cA = deck.get(a);
   deck.set(a, deck.get(b));
   deck.set(b, cA);
}
```

That's code will suffle your deck by switch two random cards many times.

Comment: I thought about this way of shuffling but felt the "100" or whatever you choose to use is hard to pick well. I've decided to try it out and crudely measure the randomness of resulting arrays. Seems like 100 iterations are not enough - resulting array is still somewhat sorted from smaller to larger numbers. 300 iterations seem to do the trick

Comment: thank you iluxa for your work. I set 300 iteration so